# Using group by subquery to deduplicate record set

Tags: oracle, group-by, subquery, min

I would like to know how I can return the activity Id to a parent query using a query like the following to de-duplicate the parent record set. The issue here is that using this group by or distinct I cannot find a way.

I will use all of the group by fields to determine a unique record. But, I need to use only the record with the select min(status.effective_date)

The query returns the correct date values, but I cannot link it back to the parents activity records with just that date value.

```
select min(status.effective_date) 
  from accounts 
     , address 
     , activity 
     , status 
 where accounts.par_row_id = activity.account_id 
   and address.row_id = activity.address_id
   and status.par_row_id = activity.status_id                                        
   and account.name = 'xyz'
 group by account.name, address.addr, address.ADDR_LINE_2, address.ADDR_LINE_3
        , address.ADDR_LINE_4, address.CITY, address.COUNTRY, address.X_STATE
        , address.ZIPCODE
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please read this on how to ask a question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask  You need to include the relevent table schemas, some sample, data, and exptected output.

Comment: You need to SELECT the same records that you GROUP BY... Otherwise how do you get the data that you want to be unique?

Answer (score 0):

You should try this query:

```
select min(activity.row_id) keep(dense_rank first order by status.effective_date) as activity_id
from accounts
, address
, activity
, status
where accounts.par_row_id = activity.account_id 
and address.row_id = activity.address_id
and status.par_row_id = activity.status_id
and accounts.name = 'xyz'
group by accounts.name, address.addr, address.ADDR_LINE_2, address.ADDR_LINE_3
    , address.addr_line_4, address.city, address.country, address.x_state
    , address.ZIPCODE;
```